# How to: Migrate ASP.NET Web Service Code to the Windows Communication Foundation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to migrate an ASP.net ASMX web service to WCF per the article below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738697.aspx

I am not sure what to do on the first part of step
9 or the add to solution part.

9.Run ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe) to generate a WCF client class from the WSDL. Add the generated class module to the solution.

`enter code here`my URL is http://mysite.edu/northwind.asmx?wsdl

Can someone please clarify for me.

Comment: Did you click on the link in step 9? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx

Comment: consider using ASP.NET Web API  also

Answer (score 1):

Running `svcutil` will generate an interface that you can build your service from.

So running this:

```
svcutil http://mysite.edu/northwind.asmx?wsdl
```

will ouput a `.cs` file that contains the interface that you need to implement in your WCF service class.

Finally, you will need to host your service somewhere, a local process, IIS, etc.

Comment: keep in mind that svcutil is a COMMAND LINE tool, not a instruction in your code

Comment: ok I have used svcutil and I have a .cs and output, how to I add this .cs to my solution? do I create  anew project in the solution and add it or just add it to the main webservice solution?

Comment: ok I have used svcutil and I have a .cs and output, how to I add this .cs to my solution? do I create anew project in the solution and add it or just add it to the main webservice solution?

Comment: If you have a service project already, add it to that, if not then create a new project for the service itself.

Comment: I have a solution with 1 webservice project and 3 class library projects for the business layer and data access. and one windows form as a test harness so create a new project ?